# how to name a critical section in openmp in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, openmp

I want to name a critical section in openmp

I names it like this:

```
#pragma omp critical [RawImageFile]
```

and I am getting this error:

```
error C3005: '[' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'critical' directive
```

if I use it in this way:

```
#pragma omp critical RawImageFile
```

I am getting this error:

```
error C3005: 'RawImageFile' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'critical' directive
```

if I use it in this way:

```
#pragma omp critical "RawImageFile"
```

I am getting this error:

```
 error C3005: 'string' : unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'critical' directive
```

What is the correct syntax to name a critical section in opnmp in visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using round-brackets i.e. 
`#pragma omp critical (RawImageFile)`
not square-brackets. (The square-brackets in the description in the OpenMP specification are part of the syntax description and mean "optional"; they're not tokens which should be included in your code).